# How do I recognize if it's an error code or just an int?

Tags: php

I learned that I can define my error codes like this:

```
class Hello
{
    /** My own error codes */
    const OK    = 0;
    const ERROR = 1;
    const OTHER = 2;

    function Test()
    {
        /** Return the error code if an error was occurred */
        if(an_error_occurred)
            return self::ERROR;

        /** Simulate some simple result. */
        return rand(0, 10);
    }
}
```

but I have some trouble about this:

```
if($Hello->Test() == Hello::ERROR)
    exit('Something happened.');
```

It'll still exit even there's no error occurred but the value which $Hello->Test() gave equals 1,

how do I solve this problem?

Or there's an better way to define my own error code?

Comment: Or `false` and check with `===`

Comment: You have to make sure to keep your class constants and return value sets disjoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't mix meanings for return values. As others have mentioned, Exceptions are pretty much made for this.

```
class Hello
{
    function Test()
    {
        /** Return the error code if an error was occurred */
        if (an_error_occurred)
            throw new Exception("An error occurred.");

        /** Simulate some simple result. */
        return rand(0, 10);
    }
}
```

And when calling it, you'd do this:

```
try {
   $foo = $hello->Test();
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
   echo "There was a problem: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The code inside the catch block only executes if the exception is thrown inside the *Test* method. You can create your own exception types to customize this further for different types of errors.

Check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: But I will use `$Hello->Test()` in many different places, what if I don't want to put the try catch block each time I use it?

Comment: you should use try catch whenever you use it. you would otherwise be doing and if block to test for an error so there's little extra work in a try catch and much greater safety. you can also choose to ignore the error and catch it higher up the stack for example. best to create your own exception classes if you're doing that of course.

Comment: If you don't deal with exceptions in a method that throws them, PHP itself will throw an error. So you need to try/catch one way or another.  

If, in a specific instance, you don't care if an exception is thrown or not -- which is unusual, since an error condition tends to be rather important -- you can provide an empty catch block that does nothing.  

Doing this, however, is generally frowned upon. Often amateur programmers will litter their code with inappropriately empty catch blocks, causing all kinds of invisible problems.